# Function call inside another function not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with 2 blocks, the first one adds html in some page elements, and the second populates the input fields on a form. I cannot get them to work. I mean, only one works at a time.

```
function popReadMsg(div_id, msg_id, msg, sender, receiver, sent, msg_vid_id) 
{

    $('#msg_sender').html(sender);
    $('#msg_sent').html(sent);
    $('#msg_body').html(msg)
    $('#vid_id').html(vid_id);

    // this part does not work unless I remove the top block.
    $('#reply_recipient').prop('value', sender);
    $('#reply_sender').prop('value', receiver);
    $('#reply_vid_id').prop('value', vid_id);
}
```

I tried wrapping the second block inside a function and call it:

```
function popReadMsg(div_id, msg_id, msg, sender, receiver, sent, msg_vid_id) 
{

    $('#msg_sender').html(sender);
    $('#msg_sent').html(sent);
    $('#msg_body').html(msg)
    $('#vid_id').html(vid_id);

    populateFields(sender, receiver, msg_vid_id);
}

function populateFields(sender, receiver, msg_vid_id) 
{
    $('#reply_recipient').prop('value', sender);
    $('#reply_sender').prop('value', receiver);
    $('#reply_vid_id').prop('value', vid_id);

}
```

The HTML:

```
     <div class="read_more_inner_wrapper">
                         <p class="output_msg2"></p>
                            <table border="0">

                            <tr>
                                <td><p id="msg_sender"></p></td>
                                <td><p id="msg_sent"></p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><p id="msg_body"></p></td>

                        </tr>  
                            </table>


                 </div>

               <div class="hide reply_form" >

               <form class="msg_form" onSubmit="return false">
                  <input type="text" name="reply_sender" id="reply_sender" >
                   <input type="text" name="reply_recipient" id="reply_recipient" >
                   <input type="text" name="reply_vid_id" id="reply_vid_id">
                    <textarea id="reply_msg" name="reply_msg" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Write your reply here"></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" onClick="replyMsg();" value="Send">
               </form>


                </div>
```

No success :(

Any help is welcome,
Mike

Comment: Show the HTML for the elements `#msg_sender`, `#msg_sent`, `#msg_body`, `#vid_id`, `#reply_recipient`, `#reply_sender` and `#reply_vid_id`, please.

Comment: Just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
$('#vid_id').html(vid_id);
```

As far as I  see, 'vid_id' is not defined (there's a parameter called 'div_id', maybe a typo?), so this line will throw an 'div_id is undefined' error and the function will stop executing. When you remove the first block of code, this doesn't happen.

You should learn to use the console, every modern browser has it in their developer tools. It would have helped you to find this error in a second.

Comment: Rightly so, for ignoring that every browser has a JavaScript error console that tells you about stuff like this.